# ObjectManager deprecated - how to create objects now?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

In TYPO3 V11 the ObjectManager is marked as deprecated, and I want to know how to replace it.
In most cases, I can use constructor with DependencyInjection, as it is recommended in the Deprecation Log #90803 (1).

But how about creating Objects, usually necessary in Scheduler Task or Middleware?
Before I created objects with this code, and ObjectManager created all Dependency Injections:

```
$myService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get(MyService::class);
```

But when using only GeneralUtility, I get this Exception:

```
$myService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyService::class);

Exception: Too few arguments to function MyService::__construct(), 
0 passed in GeneralUtility.php on line 3220 and exactly 3 expected
```

The missing 3 arguments are in the constructor of MyService. But I don't know how to get this fixed now in a good way?

If you say: use Dependency Injection for your Middleware class, I don't think this is a good solution.
Middleware runs at every TYPO3 call, and I want to check first if the required parameters are set, before I start creating objects. This is a performance issue if these objects are automatically created at every call.

(1) https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.4/Deprecation-90803-DeprecationOfObjectManagergetInExtbaseContext.html

Answer (score 1):

This really simple to solve - in your case:

```
$myService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyService::class, $argument1, $argument2, $argument3);
```

This is the same as:

```
$myService = new MyService($argument1, $argument2, $argument3);
```

Comment: For some classes it can be quite some pain to prepare all the required arguments.

Comment: Just to prevent any confusion: `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyService::class, $argument1, $argument2, $argument3)` and `new MyService($argument1, $argument2, $argument3)` may often have the same result, they are not the same. `makeInstance` also handles things like singletons, class aliases (xclass), some dependency injection, etc. The 2 lines are not interchangeable.